# How to Disconnect/Reconnect SVN from JDeveloper12c?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I'm using TortoiseSVN in my Oracle MAF application, recently svn server has been moved to another server. So I need to disconnect svn from earlier server URL into new server URL.

So I changed the server url from <kbd>Team</kbd>-> <kbd>Versions</kbd> -> <kbd>Subversion</kbd> -> <kbd>SVN_Connec</kbd> in JDeveloper12c.

After changing this, still it is pointing to existing svn server. Can you please help in this?

Please let me know, if you want any more details regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following step.

<kbd>Team</kbd> -> <kbd>Subversion</kbd> -><kbd>Create Connection</kbd> -><kbd>Manually Create</kbd>-> Add your URL and credentials.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it will create new connection. But how can I disconnect old url and reconnect with this new url? Actually my old svn url is expired, server is no-longer available now.

Comment: There is one folder .svn in your project location. you can remove it

Comment: yes, I have tried that also. When I adding new url, still it is taking existing one.

Comment: Then i think if one project connects to a server then it cannot be changed to new one

Comment: You have to... One of my senior told like that.

Comment: Not exactly, but I created another workspace and checkout code from svn then incorporate changes manually.